# infer_datetime_format with parse_date taking more time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I was going through pandas documentation. And it quoted that
[image]

I have a sample csv data file.

```
Date
22-01-1943
15-10-1932
23-11-1910
04-05-2000
02-02-1943
01-01-1943
28-08-1943
31-12-1943
22-01-1943
15-10-1932
23-11-1910
04-05-2000
02-02-1943
01-01-1943
28-08-1943
31-12-1943
22-01-1943
15-10-1932
23-11-1910
04-05-2000
02-02-1943
01-01-1943
28-08-1943
31-12-1943
22-01-1943
15-10-1932
23-11-1910
04-05-2000
02-02-1943
01-01-1943
28-08-1943
31-12-1943
```

Next I tried

```
In [174]: %timeit df = pd.read_csv("a.csv", parse_dates=["Date"])
1.5 ms ± 178 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [175]: %timeit df = pd.read_csv("a.csv", parse_dates=["Date"], infer_datetime_format=True)
1.73 ms ± 45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So, according to the documentation it should be less time. Is my understanding correct? Or on what data does the statement hold good?

Update:
Pandas version - '1.0.5'

Comment: @ALollz Updated question with pandas version

Comment: Yeah, my feeling is that the "faster parsing" is now not really an issue: This is an old answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480839/slow-pd-to-datetime. You can see that one of the date formats used to take 14 second to parse, but using infer freq it would take only like ~300 ms (probably like pd.__version__ 0.23 or something). Now with 1.0.5 that format is parsed in a blazing 9ms. So there *might* be some weird format for which you'd still see that slow parsing automatically (in which case infer_datetieme_format` will save a HUGE amount of time) but not in this case

Comment: For reference, the performance improvement was implemented in v 0.25.0: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/25922. Seems like basically everything that can be inferred now has a fast cython parsing that will be used instead of `dateutil.parser.parser`. But maybe there's some straggler

Comment: This seems like a pretty small CSV, where the one-time-cost of inferring a format may take longer than the accumulated per-item saving. Have you tried parsing files of significant length?

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is add `dayfirst = True`

```
%timeit df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/k_sego/Dates.csv", parse_dates=["Date"],dayfirst = True, infer_datetime_format=True)
1.96 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Compared to

```
%timeit df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/k_sego/Dates.csv", parse_dates=["Date"])
2.38 ms ± 182 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

and

```
%timeit df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/k_sego/Dates.csv", parse_dates=["Date"], infer_datetime_format=True)
3.02 ms ± 670 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The solution is to reduce the number of choices read_csv has to do things.